# Refined f- and h-partition polynomials of the associahedra

Tags: co.combinatorics, at.algebraic-topology, ac.commutative-algebra, real-analysis, convex-polytopes

The f-polynomials, $F_n(x)$ (cf. OEIS [A126216](https://oeis.org/A126216), [A033282](https://oeis.org/A033282), and [A086810](https://oeis.org/A086810)), and the h-polynomials, $H_n(x)$ (cf. [A001263](https://oeis.org/A001263), the Narayana polynomials), of the family of simple convex polytopes the associahedra for the Coxeter group $A_n$, or Stasheff polytopes, are related by the simple analytic equation

$$F_n(x-1) = H_n(x).$$

McCammond in "[Noncrossing partitions in surprising locations](http://www.math.ucsb.edu/~jon.mccammond/papers/nc-survey-official.pdf)" presents a geometric/combinatoric path between the f- and h-polynomials of associahedra.

The f-polynomial $F_n(x)$ enumerates (is the o.g.f. of) the number of k-dimensional faces of the n-dimensional associahedron. Refined, signed versions of the f-polynomials for the associahedra, enumerating and labelling to a finer degree the faces of the associahedra, are given in [A133437](https://oeis.org/A133437) as

$$FP_n(a_1,a_2,...) = (1/n!) [g(x)D_x]^n x|_{x=0}$$

with

$$g(x) = 1 / D_x f(x)= 1/ [a_1 + 2a_2 x + \cdots].$$

These partition polynomials give the coefficients of the power series that is the formal compositional inverse of the formal power series, or ordinary generating functions (o.g.f.s),

$$f(x) = a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + \cdots $$

and also correspond to enumerating dissections by polygons of polygons (see "[Polygonal dissections and reversions](http://arxiv.org/abs/1401.7194)" by Schuetz and Whieldon) as well as aspects of other combinatorial constructs, such as the Dyck lattice paths of [A126216](https://oeis.org/A126216). For some more details see [A145271](https://oeis.org/A145271), [MO-Q](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/272583/lodays-characterization-and-enumeration-of-faces-of-associahedra-stasheff-poly), and [MO-A](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/214927/important-formulas-in-combinatorics/215203#215203).

The corresponding h-polynomials for the associahedra enumerate noncrossing partitions, and the corresponding refinement [A134264](https://oeis.org/A134264) gives the partition polynomials $HP_n(b_0,b_1,...)$ for the compositional inverse of $f(x)$ in terms of the coefficients of the power series for the reciprocal

$$h(x) = x / f(x) = b_0 + b_1x + b_2 x^2 z + \cdots .$$

These partition polynomials are generated by

$$HP_n = (1/n!)[g(x)D_x]^n x|_{x=0}$$

with

$$g(x) = 1 / D_x [f(x)] = 1/ D_x[x/b(x)]$$

$$ = 1 /D_x [x/[b_0 + b_1 x + \cdots]]$$

and enumerate and label to a finer degree the noncrossing partitions as well as the Dyck lattice paths [A125181](https://oeis.org/A125181). For examples of the enumeration and labelling, see "[Appell polynomials, cumulants, noncrossing partitions, Dyck paths, and inversion](https://tcjpn.wordpress.com/2014/12/23/appell-ops-cumulants-noncrossing-partitions-dyck-lattice-paths-and-inversion/)" at my blog site.

Analytically, the refined f- and h-partition polynomials are related by the partition transformation [A263633](https://oeis.org/A263633), a refined binomial convolution, connecting the indeterminates $a_n$ to $b_n$.

**Question: What are some purely geometric/combinatoric paths/transformations, as opposed to the analytic path/transformation just skeched, between the refined f-an h-partition polynomials?**

Comment: I am not sure I understand you correctly: would an answer to the question "why is the h-polynomial of the associahedron equal to the generating function of noncrossing set partitions according to the number of blocks?" be satisfying?

Comment: @ChristianStump, I revised and generalized the question. Hope it's clearer now.

Comment: Okay, I don't know about these refined versions, sorry -- I plan to take a closer look over the summer...

Comment: @ChristianStump, the description of the enumeration and labelling of noncrossing partitions and Dyck paths in my blog post might be helpful.

Comment: @ChristianStump ;   See also my answer to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/422539/infinite-dimensional-involutions-infinitely-large-sets-of-multivariate-polynomi?noredirect=1#comment1139313_422539